# Duplicate contacts in Multi-Org architecture

Tags: marketing-cloud, architecture, multi-org, sfmc-business-unit

In a Multi-Org scenario in Marketing Cloud when 'All contacts' and 'All subscribers' are shared between all the BUs, is it possible that different contacts from different Orgs have the same ContactID? If yes, what could happen?

I am not really sure how this ID is generated.

As far as I read, the IDs are autogenerated for each Org so, that case of having the same ID in different Org could happen. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No :)

[Salesforce record ids are globally unique](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004383&language=en_US&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) (no matter what type of org or which pod/stack) so you won't run into duplicate issues from using Multi Org setup.